# Weird box that I can't get rid of on the viewport

Tags: outliner

[image]

When I made alt b this red box outliner showed up and no matter what I do I couldn't get rid of what should I do. I restarted blender and nothing has changed.

Comment: CTRL- ALT-B should  get rid of it.

Comment: exectly all I need was hold ctrl thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In the viewport:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to remove a render region.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to discard a clipping region.

Comment: You are right! I will update my answer. Thanks